# Nginx docker configuration is failing

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have attempted to build a Django / Gunicorn / Nginx configuration to run on AWS.  The database container is running separately.  When performing the docker-compose build step, however, the nginx step is failing.  The files are shown below:

The dockerfile.prod:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    container_name: app
    command: gunicorn The6ix.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
    networks:
      - dbnet
    expose:
      - 8000
    environment:
      aws_access_key_id: ${aws_access_key_id}
      aws_secret_access_key: ${aws_secret_access_key}

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:


networks:
  dbnet:
    external: true
```

My nginx Dockerfile (in ./nginx folder):

```
FROM nginx:1.21-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

My nginx.conf file (in ./nginx folder):

```
upstream The6ix {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://The6ix;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/app/web/mediafiles/;
    }
```

The error log from my nginx container is as follows:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2022/01/03 17:33:59 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "web:8000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:2
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "web:8000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:2
```

Some posts have mentioned usage of the volume creation step in the .yaml file as being the culprit.  But is there a better way to sequence this to enable correct run of nginx?

Answer (score 0):

I had suspected that the error was the result of my configuration copy.  In the end, it was actually a network error.  The following modifications corrected the issue:

In a shell:

```
docker network create nginx_network
```

Modification to the docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn The6ix.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    networks:
      - dbnet
      - nginx_network
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      aws_access_key_id: ${aws_access_key_id}
      aws_secret_access_key: ${aws_secret_access_key}

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    depends_on:
      - web
    networks:
      - nginx_network

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:


networks:
  dbnet:
    external: true
  nginx_network:
    external: true
```